# Getting IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds when trying to use Pandas.DataFrame.plot.hexbin

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am modeling NBA shot data using Python's `matplotlib` library and `Pandas`.
Here is the line that is causing the error:

```
shot_df.plot.hexbin(shot_df.LOC_X, shot_df.LOC_Y)
```

Where `shot_df` is the pandas `DataFrame` containing all shots, `LOC_X` is all x coordinates and `LOC_Y` is all corresponding y coordinates. `LOC_X` can be in `[-252,252]` and `LOC_Y` can be from `[-47.5,~900]`, however I am only plotting values if `LOC_Y` is less than `424.5`

While

```
pyplot.hexbin(shot_df.LOC_X,shot_df.LOC_Y)
```

generates the expected output when given the same inputs.

I've combed through the data that is throwing errors and am still lost as to why I would be getting this error. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shotChart.py", line 153, in <module>
    plt.sca(shot_df.plot.hexbin(shot_df.LOC_X, shot_df.LOC_Y))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 3880, in hexbin
    return self(kind='hexbin', x=x, y=y, C=C, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 3671, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2556, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2384, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 987, in generate
    self._make_plot()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 1602, in _make_plot
    ax.hexbin(data[x].values, data[y].values, C=c_values, cmap=cmap,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1963, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2008, in _getitem_array
    return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1371, in take
    convert=True, verify=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3619, in take
    indexer = maybe_convert_indices(indexer, n)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1750, in maybe_convert_indices
    raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Comment: you don't say what the error is.

Comment: As per ako's comments: include the full traceback in your question. In addition, it would be good to know what the various variables look like. Make a self-contained example that can be reproduced with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out how to fix this. It was using my x values `shot_df.LOC_X` as the index, which was messing up the total index range of the entire graph (only allowing index values between 0 and 11). Because `Pandas.DataFrame.plot.hexbin` is just a wrapper for `Matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin`, an easier way to achieve the same result without the indexing headache is `plt.hexbin(shot_df.LOC_X,shot_df.LOC_Y)` and all the same keywords can be used.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [pandas' documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hexbin.html), the hexbin method accepts a column index (int) or column name (str). try using the column names:

```
shot_df.plot.hexbin(x='LOC_X', y='LOC_Y')
```